# Possible to translate a UNION into a JOIN somehow?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a bit of an odd question, but I was wondering, if with two tables of identical structure it would be possible to do a join to emulate a common union query, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
```

The only (hack) idea I had was to have an 'NULL row' in `table1` and have that value cross join to table 2 and then use COALESCEs for every value in table2 to 'overwrite' that in table1...I know the correct way to do this is with a union but this is more just me wondering if it's possible to translate a union into a join.

Comment: The cross join is the only alternative which comes to mind.  But, union is the appropriate thing to use here.  Why do you have the requirement to not use union?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh no, I was just curious actually, more just a challenge to see if possible.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. JOIN is for pairing up related rows horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to accept `union all` for a different purpose, you can write this as:

```
select distinct coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(t1.col2, t2.col2) as col2,
       . . . 
from (select 1 as n union all select 2) n left join
     table1 t1
     on n.n = 1 left join
     table2
     on n.n = 2;
```

Note the use of `select distinct`.  Your question specifies `union`, which removes duplicates.

If that use of `union all` is too much for you, you can use a similar idea with alternative formulations. For instance:

```
select distinct coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(t1.col2, t2.col2) as col2,
       . . . 
from information_schema.tables t left join
     table1 t1
     on t.table_name = 'table1' left join
     table2
     on t.table_name = 'table2'
where t.table_name in ('table1', 'table2') and
      t.table_catalog = ? and
      t.table_schema = ?;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done in MySQL, but if you're using a version of SQL that supports `FULL OUTER JOIN`, you can use an always false `JOIN` condition to emulate a `UNION` e.g.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.a, t2.a) AS a,
       COALESCE(t1.b, t2.b) AS b
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON 0 = 1
```

It can't be done in MySQL because it doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, and the way to emulate `FULL OUTER JOIN` is with a `UNION` of a `LEFT JOIN` and  a `RIGHT JOIN`.

**Update**

Using row numbers, it is possible to emulate the `UNION` with a `JOIN` of the two tables where either row number is 1, then using a `LEFT JOIN` to the second table again to duplicate the row where both row numbers are 1. Then some convoluted row ordering sorts the rows into the same order as the `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) AS rn
  FROM table1
),
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) AS rn
  FROM table2
)
SELECT CASE WHEN c3.rn = 2 THEN CTE2.a 
            WHEN CTE2.rn = 1 THEN CTE1.a 
            ELSE CTE2.a END AS a,
       CASE WHEN c3.rn = 2 THEN CTE2.b
            WHEN CTE2.rn = 1 THEN CTE1.b 
            ELSE CTE2.b END AS b
FROM CTE1
JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.rn = 1 OR CTE2.rn = 1
LEFT JOIN CTE2 c3 ON CTE1.rn = 1 AND CTE2.rn = 1 AND c3.rn IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY CTE2.rn, 
         CASE WHEN COALESCE(c3.rn, 1) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CTE1.rn
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7af28a037326e152a619555022153177)

Note I've used CTEs and window functions (available as of MySQL 8) to generate row numbers; there are many ways to emulate row numbers in earlier versions and you would need to replace the CTEs with subqueries in that case.

Comment: The question is tagged `mysql`, which doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: And in MySQL, the way to emulate `FULL OUTER JOIN` is by using `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar that is why I prefixed the answer the way I did. I think the question is general enough that it is worth explaining how it can be done.

Comment: Maybe the prefix should make it clear that this doesn't include MySQL. "You can't do this in MySQL, but ..."

Comment: @Barmar that's a fair comment, I've updated the answer and also added the explanation of how you emulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to explain why it's not possible.

Comment: @Nick cool thanks for the answer. Now without a full outer join, is there any way to emulate it? (I was thinking possibly a cross-join).

Comment: @David542 having slept on it I did come up with another alternative.

Comment: @Nick wow that's pretty hardcore, thanks for taking the time, and glad you could the exercise challenging!

Comment: @Nick one question here -- why did you decide to add in the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) AS rn` -- what does that do effectively?

Comment: The row numbers are used for joining the two tables to limit the rows returned. Consider for two 3 row tables, a cross join would return pairs of rows from each table of (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3). Using row numbers I can then cut that down to (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1) and then I use the `LEFT JOIN` to duplicate (1,1) so that I now have al the rows from each table, the rows from the first table are (*,1) and the rows from the second are (1,*). The `CASE` expressions then select the appropriate value to display based on those pairs.

Comment: If you were asking about `ORDER BY RAND()`, SQL requires that the rows be ordered by something, and I didn't have an `id` type field in my sample data. If you did have one in your table, you would use `ORDER BY id` instead.